# query optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization

I need newest 4 product from different 4 categories. this query is not working

```
SELECT 
  ProductID,ProductName,thumb
  FROM 
  tbproduct 
  WHERE 
  status =2 
GROUP BY 
`CATEGORYID` 
ORDER BY 
`ProductID` DESC 
LIMIT 4
```

so i first order by all records.and use following query...

```
SELECT 
ProductID, ProductName, thumb 
FROM 
  (
  SELECT 
  ProductID,ProductName,thumb,CATEGORYID 
  FROM 
  tbproduct 
  WHERE 
  status =2 
  ORDER BY 
  `ProductID` DESC
  ) AS tmp 
GROUP BY 
`CATEGORYID` 
ORDER BY 
`ProductID` DESC 
LIMIT 4
```

this query is slow can any one suggest me its fast query. I a using MySQL.

Comment: 1. What is the point of the inner qury if there's no limit there? 2. can you show explain of that query?

Comment: dont use sub-query, it will reduce the speed. can u tell me what your going to get from this query.? i dont understand your need.

Comment: i need those product which are latest one product according to every category.if i use only group by following by order by then that query not takes latest record. so first i order by all record.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply use:

```
SELECT 
  ProductID,ProductName,thumb,CATEGORYID 
  FROM tbproduct 
  WHERE status=2
  GROUP BY CATEGORYID
  ORDER BY ProductID DESC
  LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT 
  Max(ProductID), ProductName,thumb
  FROM 
  tbproduct 
  WHERE 
  status =2 
GROUP BY 
`CATEGORYID` 
ORDER BY 
 ProductID DESC 
LIMIT 4
```

Does this not work?

---

Not sure if this will help, see the updated query. See usage of [Group-by Aggragate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max).

Note: *This will not reliably return other columns.* Please look here for [left-self-exclusion join](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#101)

Comment: no this query not bring latest 4 record from every category. so i not used this query.this query first group by record and then order by those record which are the result of group by

Comment: @Nishant: sorry, I posted exactly your answer at the same time... should I remove?

Comment: @nishant, @ marco i need newest 4 product from different 4 categories and these query will not work. i already try it.

Comment: @Marco no problem, do not delete your post. It happens all the time at SO. Welcome.

Comment: @nishant not working this query. the result of my query is 76,55,40,28 categories. and you query result is  55,40,28,3

Comment: @Deepa see this article http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#101 -- it solves the same issue that you are facing without subquerying.

Comment: @nishant : this is the exact solution : SELECT 
  Max(ProductID), ProductName,thumb
  FROM 
  tbproduct 
  WHERE 
  status =2 
GROUP BY 
`CATEGORYID` 
ORDER BY 
 Max(ProductID) DESC 
LIMIT 4............... thanks for idea of max

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
ProductID, ProductName, thumb 
FROM tbproduct 
WHERE ProductID in (
  SELECT max(ProductID)
  FROM tbproduct
  WHERE status = 2
  GROUP BY CATEGORYID
  ORDER BY ProductID DESC
  LIMIT 4
) ORDER BY ProductID DESC
```

That should do.